# Implementing data binding in a MVVM framework

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, system.reactive

I'm developing a MVVM framework (C#) and I'm looking for information on how to implement data binding  / synchronization (one-way, two-way, multi-binding, etc.). Also, is there any other frameworks I should consider utilizing, e.g. Reactive Extensions?

Comment: you need to support INotifyPropertyChanged one way or another. There are already good MVVM frameworks. If you really think you need to create one yourself, you can look at them too to get ideas.

Comment: That is under the assumption he is building WPF. That interface is not a requirement if he is targeting a different presentation framework

Comment: I'm targeting mono 2.6 utilized by unity3d - (similar to .net framework 3.5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several MVVM frameworks that exist for WPF. You can use them to provide some guidance with your framework.

- [Prism](https://compositewpf.codeplex.com)
- [MVVMLite](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)

I'm not a web developer, but I also believe that Angular and Knockout follow the MVVM pattern as well for web development.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know they were open-source.